# How to add number from 3 different files in 3 different directories?

Tags: bash

[image]

Each 10 comes from a different file and each of those files come from a different directory. How would I add them together to and get the output of Popeye 30?

This is what I have so far to get the three 10 in a column:

```
cat "$x" | grep "$candidate" | grep -oe '\([0-9.]*\)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to pipe `awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'` at the end of your result like this:

```sh
echo "Enter candidate:
Popeye
10
10
10" | grep "$candidate" | grep -oe '\([0-9.]*\)' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

If you are going to be adding anything beyond `2147483647 (2^31)`, `printf` would be preferable over `print`, because awk uses a 32 bit signed integer representation and you may experience a strange behavior in some awk versions.

```sh
echo "Enter candidate:
Popeye
10
10
10" | grep "$candidate" | grep -oe '\([0-9.]*\)' | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use awk to get the sum of the last three lines:

```
echo "$candidate $(cat "$x" | grep "$candidate" | grep -oe '\([0-9.]*\)' | tail -3 | awk '{i+=$1} END{print i}')"
```